# Как отредактировать информацию о завершении заказа?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На стадии завершения покупки выходит информация о заказе и реквизиты для оплаты. В каком файле отредактировать эту информацию, какие поля выводить а какие нет? К примеру не водится ФИО.

[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 1):

Не надо править файл. В WooCommerce существуют сотни хуков для решения разнообразных задач. Добавьте следующий код в functions.php

```
// Добавляем фильтр
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Функция фильтра - $fields проходят через фильтр
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    // Добавляем поле отчество
    $fields['billing']['billing_middle_name'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Middle Name', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Middle Name', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => false,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
    );
    // Добавляем остальные поля аналогично

    return $fields;
}
```

В примере я добавил одно поле, остальные аналогично. Функции перевода __ и _x можете заменить строковыми константами на русском.

**UPDATE**

Если стоит задача модифицировать вывод на странице `/checkout/order-received/...`, которая выводится после оформления заказа, то нужно править шаблон `\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\order\order-details-customer.php`. Его нужно скопировать в папку своей темы `yourtheme/woocommerce/order/order-details-customer.php`.

Comment: Вы меня верно поняли? Нужно не добавление полей сделать, а отображение заполненных полей на последней странице (/checkout/order-received). К примеру было заполнено поле "Фамилия", но оно не отобразилось на последней странице.

Comment: Неверно понял. Если бы в вопросе сразу был дан адрес страницы `/checkout/order-received/`, я понял бы быстрее. Дополнил ответ.